# Magento. Atributes on Layered Navigation create their own page

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, layered-navigation, seo

I have started working on a Magento site, no information how it was configured.

It is using Magento 1.8.

On the catalog page, I see sidebar includes some attributes which has been configured to appear on the layered navigation, so far is good.

I have noticed per each combination of these attribute a page is created, in our case we have a lot of combinations and it will be a nightmare for SEO.

Is there a way we can filter using parameters instead of a custom URL for each combination?